# Multiple Selenium port localhost Issue

Tags: python, selenium

**My simple need:**

I want to open two IE browsers on two different Selenium ports on localhost

**My Setup**

**My Selenium Server Setup**

Selenium server (2.2.0v) running on Win 7 at port 4444 and 4445

**My Selenium Client Setup**

Selenium Client - Selenium RC on Python 2.7 on same Win 7 where Selenium server is running

My code that just opens two browsers on two different Selenium ports is here:

```
# C:\Python27\python.exe
from selenium import selenium
def localhost_issue():
    '''
    This method will simply open two IE browsers on two different Selenium
    ports on localhost

    This FAILS to happens because only one browser opens at the end

    '''
    myserver = 'localhost'

    s1 = selenium(myserver, 4444, '*iexplore', 'http://www.google.com/')
    s1.start()
    s1.open('/')

    s2 = selenium(myserver, 4445, '*iexplore', 'http://www.msn.com/')
    s2.start()
    s2.open('/')    # FAILS BECAUSE browser 1 is overwritten by browser 2
localhost_issue()
```

This happens only with IE (not firefox). Any help?

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

I hate to be the bearer of bad news but this is because Firefox works under profiles but IE is a different beast, though this applies to Selenium Grid it definitely applies to your problem as well: http://svn.openqa.org/fisheye/browse/~raw,r=390/selenium-grid/website/src/main/webapp/faq.html#i_get_some_strange_errors_when_i_run_multiple_internet_explorer_instances_on_the_same_machine.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the help. What I have noticed is that this problem ONLY comes when using Selenium servers and client on ONE localhost!! I don't get this problem when my servers (with ports 4444 and 4445) are clients are on different machines.

Comment: Is there any issue raised for this? Do you want me to raise an issue for this?